# How to get the page url where from php file is called

Tags: php

I have a file named insert.php when this file is called through

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://insert.com/insert.php"></script>`
```

from a page example.com/xyz.html collects some information about this xyz page and process this information. I want to get the url of page example.com/xyz.html or other page where from insert.php file is called. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try it to get the url from where insert.php is called.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** .

But please note (according to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) ):

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>       The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents
>   will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as
>   a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.